# Link versus onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclicklistener

I have a web application that exclusively uses AJAX so there are no full refreshes and everything is set up as

```
<a href="javascript:...()">
```

It works really well on Chrome and Firefox but IE asks to confirm the page reload every time I click on anything. Would it be better to change the links to

```
href="#"
```

and make the functionality into onClick?

Thanks.

Comment: Just don't use inline javascript: Solved?

Comment: have you tried doing that? and what happened?

Comment: it needs to be inline because there lists with different ids being passed to the same function, as in function('1'), function('2'), etc... thoughts?

Comment: As in what? There is never really a need for inline js @user988129

Comment: @user988129 You don't need to use inline events. Use `data-` attributes to hold the element-specific data.

Comment: id love to do that but are data attributes compatible in ie 6,7,8? the people using this may be using older crap browsers.

Comment: @user988129 jQuery should allow you to use data attributes in older "crap" browsers.

Comment: This has been asked before, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Answer (score 2):

Just stop using inline javascript all together. You don't need it.

Output the id associated to the element in a data attribute:

```
<a href="#" data-id="34" class="list-item">listitem1</a>
```

Now you can bind to those click events from an external js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".list-item").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // stop jump to top
        var theId = $(this).attr("data-id"); // get the id
        someFunction(theId); // execute some terribly written function
    });
});
```

This *does* work cross-browser.

Comment: +1 - It's worth noting that in place of `.attr('data-id')` you could use `.data('id')`

Answer (score 0):

With "href='#'" you will probably need to preventDefaults on your JS function so the page doesn't go to top because of the '#' anchor.

I would do:

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="someclass" rel='2'>
```

JS

```
$('.someclass').on('click', function(){
   var value = $(this).attr('rel');
   // use 'value' as you would normaly do with your function(2)
});
```

Or this one:

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="someclass" rel='34'>
```

JS

```
$('.someclass').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

   var value = $(this).attr('rel');
   // use 'value' as you would normaly do with your function(34)
});
```

Comment: that would work except i have a list of items that are all calling the same function, as in lissitem1 - function('1'), listitem2 - function('2'), etc...

Comment: @user988129 Sounds like you could use the index+1 rather than hardcoding the id. or modify the so-called `function` to work properly based on the clicked element rather than an arbitrary number.

Comment: the parameters wont necessarily match the id though - the html generated may be listitem1 - function('34') listitem2 - function('2'). sorry to be a pain...

Comment: Right... but having to do it that way just screams bad programming. that sounds terrible to maintain.

Comment: You could put the value in some dumb html attribute like "rel='1'"... So you could get those values with $(this).attr(rel)

Comment: I edited the code to exemplify what i mean. Thats a little ugly but I couldnt come up with a better idea at the moment